# Detect device and apply and apply specific css

Tags: javascript, resize, responsive

I have a little question for all of you !

I will try to apply mobile stylesheet only if the user is on a mobile. 
If the user is on desktop only the desktop's stylesheet will be apply even after resizing the window.

Here is the result I'm looking : 
• [enter link description here](http://www.disneylandparis.fr)

When you resize your windows the mobile's stylesheet is not apply because you are on a desktop version

easy or not  ? Help me please 
Thank's a lot

Comment: Why wouldn't you allow the style for smaller screen to be applied when the desktop browser window becomes smaller?

Answer (score 1):

you are gonna need some javascript to detect the browser, even then it's still a difficult task to accomplish 100% of the time since there's always new browsers out there,  one of the most up to date librearies is bowser. https://github.com/ded/bowser

Answer (score 0):

You ca use css [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

For example

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

For example the above style will be applied only when the `max-width` is less than or equal to 500

Comment: I think you misunderstood my request.

I want to apply a style when it detects the mobile.
The solution offers you me (I already know) that also applies when the resize your browser window outside I do not want it

Comment: css media query takes care of it